# acumatica scheduled automated notifications, status "pending" even if messages were sent

Tags: notifications, status, schedule, acumatica

Good day, friends!

I am trying to set up a schedule of sending notifications.
All is working except the part when status of each notification "pending" even if messages were sent, and as schedule works every 5 minutes users receive same emails every 5 minutes.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you try with a longer schedule? I wonder if there's a delay between sending and the actual delivery of email. Case activity emails for example have a delay where you can cancel the sending of the email.

Comment: the problem gone after Updating our Acumatica.